# Confused about memory examination using gdb?

Tags: linux, memory, binary

I started reading Hacking, the art of exploitation and I am confused about some things regarding memory examination.

When I disassemble main, I get an output of all memories where the individual assembly instructions are, right? Each instruction does not necessarily need to append the memory address by one, that is why I might have <main+1> and then <main +3> right after. So command on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyhuJ.jpg) shows the first 20 instructions for the program. How many bytes of information does each information contain?

Now I get confused, when using i r eip, I get the location of this register, which is 0x8048384 (so is it stored as the first instruction of main?) [on the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZkG4.jpg). The value next to it, is the value it holds, here I wonder, it stores 0x00fc45c7, however this instruction is not in the output above? I thought it should point to the memory which consists the next instruction for the program.

Now comes the biggest confusion, I can observe the memory where $eip is stored and observe multiple units at once, which can be seen on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWUtK.jpg). However on this screenshot using x/2x you can see that there are two values stored in the memory and both of 4 bytes in size? Then using x/12 there are suddenly 4 words in 0x8048384 and other 4 words 0x8048394?

I just dot seem to understand how the values stored in the memory address differ based on the units I use. I also thought each memory address should contain only a byte of information?

If you need any clarification in the question please post, English is not my first language and I am not sure whether I explained this correctly.

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

> How many bytes of information does each information contain?

Anywhere from the one byte `push %ebp` to several bytes; the
instructions have no fixed length. Output from a command such as
`objdump -d a.out` may make the instruction length clearer (and will
show what the instructions are, which may be useful):

```
08048400 <main>:
 8048400:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048401:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048403:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048406:       90                      nop
 8048407:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
 804840e:       89 f6                   mov    %esi,%esi
 8048410:       83 7d fc 09             cmpl   $0x9,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
```

> Now I get confused, when using i r eip, I get the location of this
> register ...

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x8048400 <main>:       push   %ebp
0x8048401 <main+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x8048403 <main+3>:     sub    $0x8,%esp
0x8048406 <main+6>:     nop
0x8048407 <main+7>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x804840e <main+14>:    mov    %esi,%esi
0x8048410 <main+16>:    cmpl   $0x9,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
...
(gdb) i r eip
eip            0x8048406        0x8048406
```

In my version of this program `eip` points to the `nop` command which is
where `b main` halted the program under `gdb`.

> Now comes the biggest confusion, I can observe the memory where
> `$eip` is stored

```
(gdb) x/10b $eip
0x8048406 <main+6>:     0x90    0xc7    0x45    0xfc    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x804840e <main+14>:    0x89    0xf6
```

And recall the output from `objdump`, above:

```
 8048406:       90                      nop
 8048407:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
 804840e:       89 f6                   mov    %esi,%esi
```

The dump of `$eip` with 10 bytes shows the next three instructions: 90
and then c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 and then 89 f6.

> I just dot seem to understand how the values stored in the memory
> address differ based on the units I use. I also thought each memory
> address should contain only a byte of information?

`gdb` allows inspection by different widths or logical units. We can
say `x/3i` to show the next three instructions, for example:

```
(gdb) x/3i $eip
0x8048406 <main+6>:     nop
0x8048407 <main+7>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x804840e <main+14>:    mov    %esi,%esi
```

The best width selection to use will depend on the situation. On a
8-bit system you would need to look at bytes. Memory addresses on a
64-bit system should be inspected with `g` for giant, or 8 bytes.
Changing the width of the selection may change what number `gdb` will
show as a different width may result in a different pattern of bits and
therefore a different number. Also, the endianness of the CPU may
complicate matters.

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *pointer = "test";
int main(void) {
        printf("%s\n", pointer);
}
```

If we select different widths when we examine `pointer` we will get
different numbers from the different patterns of bits:

```
(gdb) p pointer
$1 = 0x8048488 "test"
(gdb) x/4c pointer
0x8048488 <_IO_stdin_used+4>:   116 't' 101 'e' 115 's' 116 't'
(gdb) x/4t pointer
0x8048488 <_IO_stdin_used+4>:   01110100        01100101        01110011        01110100
(gdb) x/t (int *)pointer
0x8048488 <_IO_stdin_used+4>:   01110100011100110110010101110100
```

Another problem is that Intel systems are little-endian (Intel
probably does not consider this to be a problem). Therefore the bit
patterns from `x/4t` and `x/t (int *)` differ slightly due to this
complication, if you look closely at them. We can instruct `gdb` to
enter big endian mode,

```
(gdb) set endian big
The target is assumed to be big endian
(gdb) x/t (int *)pointer
0x88840408:     Cannot access memory at address 0x88840408
```

but now we must enter our memory addresses backwards! The `htonl`
function call can reverse a 32-bit little endian value to a big
endian value:

```
$ cfu 'printf("%d\n", htonl(0x88840408))'
134513800
```

and then in `gdb` we can try that address:

```
(gdb) x/t (int *)134513800
0x8048488 <_IO_stdin_used+4>:   01110100011001010111001101110100
```

and now the bit pattern from the four characters matches the big-endian
form. Putting these results into a table might help:

```
            --> big endian reads this way
              t        e        s        t
x/4t (char)   01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100
big endian    01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100
            <-- yaw siht sdaer naidne elttil dna
              t        s        e        t
little endian 01110100 01110011 01100101 01110100
```

These are three ways (of many) that the bit pattern for the string
`test` could be shown by `gdb`. Different numbers will be shown
depending on how many bits you tell `gdb` to divide the input into and
the endianness of the system, all from the same pattern of bits.